# How to use only parity arguments to derive selection rules for $X$ and $P$ operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, parity

> Derive rules of selection between matrix elements of eigkets $|{l,m}\rangle$ and $|{l',m'}\rangle$ for the operator $\hat{X}$ and $\hat{P}$. Use only parity arguments.

I now that that the elements of the operators $\hat{X}$ and $\hat{P}$ between states of defined parity is only different from zero if the states have opposite polarity. However I don't know how to do it on the basis requested

Comment: There is no \ket function in Mathjax.  You can use \lt ($\lt$) or \langle ($\langle$)

Answer (score 1):

The missing piece of the puzzle is that the angular-momentum eigenstates $|l,m\rangle$ have definite parity $(-1)^l$.

However, it is important to note that if you only use parity for this calculation, you will have an incomplete picture of the selection rules: you will get a set of forbidden transitions and those are indeed forbidden, but from the set of "allowed" transitions (as regards parity) many are still forbidden.